# Access attributes of second model instead of foreign key

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a `Project` with a foreign key to a `Region`.  I want to display the region name for a project.  I can only get the region's id though.  How do I access the `name` attribute of a `Region` from a `Project`?

```
class Project(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    region = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('regions.id'))

class Region(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

@deliverables.route('/<int:cid>')
def deliv_view(cid):
    projects = Project.query.filter(Project.id == cid).all()
    return render_template('ginn/deliview.html', projects = projects)
```

```html
{{ project.region }}
```

```
3
```

Answer (score 3):

Define a foreign key column between `Project` and `Region`.  Then define a [relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/basic_relationships.html) between the two to access the other model directly.

```
class Region(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Project(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    region_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(Region.id), nullable=False)
    region = db.relationship(Region, backref='projects')

project = Project.query.get(1)
print(project.region.name)
```

This, and many other useful techniques, are described in both the [quickstart](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship) and in more depth throughout the docs.